# Panel resizes, istead of adding a scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I want my panel to hold its size and add the scrollbar when I add new User controls.

Here is how I add the user controls:

```
 int showCaseIndex = 0;
            foreach (ShowCase sc in s.scs)
            {
                ShowCaseController controller = new ShowCaseController(sc);
                ShowCaseUI scui = controller.GiveShowCase();
                scui.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X,150 * showCaseIndex);
                scui.Size = new Size(panel1.Width, 150);
                panel1.Controls.Add(scui);
                showCaseIndex++;
            }
```

I checked locked for the panel on true, and also enabled autoscroll.

EDIT: Also the user controls are not visible.

Comment: I do not see a description of the problem, nor a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set AutoSize() to False to keep the panel from growing.

Also, the Location() property is in client coords relative to its container, so using `panel1.Location.X` is most likely not what you wanted.  If you put 0 (zero) in for that value then the control would up against the Left edge inside of the panel:

```
scui.Location = new Point(0, 150 * showCaseIndex);
```